# Can't connect my mongodb cluster I created on mongodb atlas from cpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cpanel

I created a cluster on mongodb atlas and I've whitelisted all Ip addresses, I seem to be able to connect to the cluster from localhost but can't do that when I move to cpanel I get this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-fgj1f.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect`.

Here is my code `mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:<password>@cluster0-shard-00-00-fgj1f.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-fgj1f.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-fgj1f.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority');`. One thing I notice is that my script is running on the default `port:3001` I provided even though I did this `const port = process.env.PORT || 3001` I had to set an environment variable of PORT to my domain Ip? Is that right? Pls help out, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try connecting with the mongo shell or another tool to validate the config string and credential.

Comment: I'm using cpanel, how do I make the necessary installations?

Comment: I would first test with something that is simpler to use, so you can determine if the problem is in cpanel or something else.

Comment: The problem is with cpanel, Working perfectly from my localhost